# Bind attribute: pass in an array instead of defining in the parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I'm trying to pass a bind array instead of defining in the parameters. For example, this code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Create")]
    public ResultsItem Create([Bind(nameof(Person.Username), nameof(Person.Password))] Person)
    {
        ...
    }
```

It works fine, however, if it gets big, I'll have a big bind list. I wanted to define it in the class instead like below:

*Person.cs*

```
public static readonly string[] BindInclude = new[] { nameof(Username), nameof(Password) };
public ResultsItem Create([Bind(Person.BindInclude)] Person newUser)
```

However, I am getting the following error:
`An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type.`

I understand the error, however I'm wondering does anyone have a good way for doing this? Let's say I have a big class, however, I only want to bind like 6 - 10 properties. How can I do this without flooding the `Bind[()]` in controller.

Comment: Use a view model.

Comment: Yea, not but what I was looking for in this case. It's a Web API. We post data (a big single class), and that class gets saved to the db. We only want to bind few properties, not all.

Comment: View model is the best solution to avoid over posting.

Comment: So basically have a VM like PersonVM, which has like only few properties like Username, Password, and Email. Once we bind the VM, assign them to Person like Person.Username = PersonVM.Username? Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Comment: @StephenMuecke lol, I know what a ViewModel is. However, the concern was different. I guess there's no way to accomplish what's being asked. I'll look into different scenario (whether it be using VM or some other binding tactic).

Comment: lol - if you know what it is, and why they are used, then you would never be using a data model in a view in the first place, and never be using a `[Bind]` attribute

Comment: Okay then tell me why [Bind] exist. Benefit of `[Bind] Person`, the object you get back is already populated the way you want it to be. You wont need to convert it again like `Person.Name = PersonVM.Name`. And like I said, this is a Web API, there is no view or anything. This method is simple POST & Save to db.